# AQL error using shortest path language construct in ArangoDB 2.8

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

we are trying to switch to "3.0 style" of graph functions.

We run the example of the documentation:

```
FOR v, e IN OUTBOUND SHORTEST_PATH 'circles/A' TO 'circles/D' GRAPH 'traversalGraph' RETURN [v._key, e._key]
```

and it works on ArangoDB 3.0, but it doesn't in ArangoDB 2.8.11
The error is:

```
"errorNum":1501,"errorMessage":"syntax error, unexpected quoted string near '' TO 'circles/D' GRAPH 'traversa...' at position 1:46 (while parsing)"
```

Our goal is switch all queries into "3.0 style", because we want upgrade the database to 3.0, but we would like also backward compatibility.
We have read https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/2c842774b457114c571abdaa8391a038715d1458/3.3/cookbook/aql-migrating-graph-functions-to3.md and there is a section that talks about shortest_path. We tried the example, but the error is above.

Can somebody help us?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Daniele

Answer (score 0):

The [SHORTEST_PATH](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/shortest-path/) implementation you mentioned was added with 3.0.

In [ArangoDB 2.8 it didn't exist yet](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/79a11cc3101601093c05ed6a11b846b9535b6bba/Documentation/Books/AQL/Aql/GraphOperations.mdpp), and thus it won't understand this newer syntax.
So I'm afraid you won't be able to use these queries with 2.8.

If you want your application to be flexible between these two ArangoDB versions, you will have to prevail two code paths in your Application at the time being.

This is a bit uncomfortable, [but others found the efford to be worth while](https://twitter.com/dexterchief/status/766763735218257920), I hope you will too ;-)

Comment: Our software with ArangoDB 2.8 is in production for an important insurance company. So, we must guarantee backward compatibility from 2.8 to 3.0 version, and we can't switch the versions from code. :) I'm curious, why don't you add in the 2.8 release the SHORTEST_PATH implementation?

Comment: You [can forward allow the deprecated `SHORTEST_PATH`-function in 3.0](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/cookbook/AQL/MigratingGraphFunctionsTo3.html#solution-1-quick-and-dirty-not-recommended) - However the queries still have to be different in 3.0: `arangodb::SHORTEST_PATH`. As you know Jan already, maybe you want to drop him a line via jan.stuecke at arangodb.com maybe he can get a smoother solution for this issue.